# xCode 6: Views gets reset in size and position when editing another view

Tags: ios, xcode6

This is kinda driving me nuts, don´t know if I´m missing something but this is really annoying.

This is my setup:
[image]

Now, if I use the Interface builder to, for example, changing the Image View´s size by dragging in it corners, the View will just reset in size and position (and vice versa). Changing the size using Size Inspector still works fine.

The whole storyboard acts the same way.

Anyone who had a similar problem?

Comment: not enough details, please add some screen sots of the interface builder and some code

Comment: Plenty enough details here. Happens to me also so must be a bug, hopefully fixed soon as the storyboard is pretty useless at the moment.